# Efficient and secure Payment Gateway service for mobile applicaiton

Tags: payment-gateway, cordova-plugins

I would like to develop e-commerce mobile application using cordova.

i am little confused in selecting the more secured payment gateway service which is easy to integrate and available for android, blackberry10 and ios.

I had checked PayPal plugin but it is available for ios and android and not for blackberry10 as per research.

is there any single plugin which will works for all three platform ?

i had come across [IOS and android Plugin](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin).

Any help is really appreciated.